# Is there a hook I can use to run my function when point moves?

Tags: hooks, point, motion

I'd like to add some navigation context to the modeline. I can figure out where I am just fine and give the name of my function, but I don't know how to run this every time point moves.

`post-command-hook` is the only thing I've found, but it sounds like it's overkill.  Is there anything more appropriate?

Comment: Why is `post-command-hook` overkill? You may not want your hook to run every time point moves, if it is done by some elisp code. There is a lot of code that moves point in order to do stuff. Granted, it is typically done within a `save-excursion`, but still … (I don't know if code can decide whether `save-excursion` is in effect or not.)

Comment: @Harald I suppose it might not be. The documentation isn't very clear on when this hook is run (i.e. what constitutes a command). For the record, I'm 100% willing to accept 'that is in fact the right thing to use' as an answer.

Comment: `M-x elisp-index-search RET command`. A command is a function with an `interactive` form, or a keyboard macro (string or vector format).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think `post-command-hook` is what you wish to use.

It is run every time a *command* has been run. And a command is basically any interactive action, such as clicking a mouse button, typing a letter (which runs `self-insert-command`, or running a command using `M-x`.

You may wish to make sure your hook is not run while you are typing in the minibuffer. I think wrapping the body in  `(unless (window-minibuffer-p) …)` will care of that for you.

And possibly, you want your hook only to be active when you are editing certain files. In which case, you might consider making `post-command-hook` buffer local: Using

```
(add-hook 'post-command-hook #'your-hook nil :local)
```

will take care of that for you. (**Edited** to add this last point.)

Comment: Don't explicitly make hook variables buffer-local. Instead use the `LOCAL` argument when calling `add-hook`.

Comment: @phils Excellent point. I'll update the answer.