# elisp - detect line change event to trigger function

Tags: mouse, motion, events

I want to detect line change event (arrow-,arrow- or mouse click) to trigger my function call.

Below example handled arrow- arrow- but can not handle mouse click or C-n C-p line change event.

```
(defun myup(n)
  (interactive "p")
  (previous-line)
  (showme))

(defun mynext(n)
  (interactive "p")
  (next-line)
  (showme))

(defun showme()
  (let ((line (thing-at-point 'line t)))
    (when (string-match  "\\[\\([0-9a-f]+\\)\\]" line)
      (setq sha1 (match-string 1 line))
      (setq bufname "differ")
      (when (= (length (window-list)) 1)
        (split-window-vertically (floor (* 0.2 (window-height))))
        )
      (setq buffer (get-buffer-create bufname))
      (switch-to-buffer-other-window buffer)
      (erase-buffer)
      (insert sha1)
      (goto-char (point-min))
      (other-window 1))))

(define-key diff-mode-map  (kbd "<down>") 'mynext)
(define-key diff-mode-map  (kbd "<up>") 'myup)
```

What's right way to handle this case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer to “I want to detect (…) event” is usually to use the appropriate [hook](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Hooks.html#Hooks). The manual has a [list of standard hooks](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Standard-Hooks.html#Standard-Hooks). There's no hook that triggers on a line change, so the next thing is to look for a hook that triggers on any motion. [There's no hook specifically for that either, to you're down to a hook that runs every command](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/20596/is-there-a-hook-i-can-use-to-run-my-function-when-point-moves).

Keep track of the current line number in a variable, and run the desired code whenever that value changes. Untested proof-of-concept:

```
(defvar showme-last-position nil)
(make-variable-buffer-local 'showme-last-line)
(defun showme-is-on-different-line (marker)
  "Returns true if MARKER and point are on different lines."
  (save-excursion
    (if (< showme-last-position (point))
        (progn
          (beginning-of-line)
          (< showme-last-position (point)))
      (end-of-line)
      (> showme-last-position (point)))))
(defun showme-if-needed ()
  ;; Create marker if needed
  (if (null showme-last-position)
      (setq showme-last-position (make-marker)))
  ;; Is marker on a different line from point, or uninitialized?
  (when (or (null (marker-position showme-last-position))
            (showme-is-on-different-line showme-last-position))
      ;; Update marker and run showme
      (set-marker-position showme-last-position (point))
      (showme)))
```

(Note that my way of detecting a line change is faster than recomputing the line number — `line-number-at-pos` can be slow in a large file.)

I haven't reviewed your code, there may be a better trigger than a change in the line number. You may want to preprocess the buffer and add [overlays](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Overlays.html#Overlays). [Font Lock mode](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Font-Lock-Mode.html#Font-Lock-Mode) has facilities for that, and can do the job lazily based on what parts of the buffer get shown so that opening a large file doesn't take forever.

One thing I do notice in your code is that the way you return to the original buffer and window is unreliable: `other-window` might not do the right thing depending on the window configuration. Whenever you want to move and then return to the original place, use [`save-excursion`](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Excursions.html#index-save_002dexcursion).